# Function not adding element to doubly linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I have been writing a doubly linked list in C, and even though the function for inserting an element to the back of the list seems correct to me, the element is not added. Debugging showed that the values are assigned to the corresponding *Pacijent* instances, however, the *front* and *back* of the list are still `NULL`.

Here's the code:

```
struct Pacijent
{
    char ime[10];
    [...]
    Pacijent *prev;
    Pacijent *next;
};

Pacijent noviPacijent(char i[], char p[], char io[], int jmb[], double v, double t, int s)
{
    Pacijent *novi = (Pacijent*)malloc(sizeof(Pacijent));
    memcpy(novi->ime, i, strlen(i)+1);
    [...]
    return *novi;
}

struct Lista
{
    Pacijent *front;
    Pacijent *back;
};

void assign(Pacijent p1, Pacijent p2)
{
    memcpy(p1.ime, p2.ime, strlen(p1.ime)+1);
    [...]
}

void insertBack(Pacijent p, Lista l)
{
    Pacijent *novi = (Pacijent*)malloc(sizeof(Pacijent));
    assign(*novi, p);
    if (l.back == NULL)
    {
        l.front = l.back = novi;
        novi->prev = NULL;
        novi->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        novi->prev = l.back;
        l.back->next = novi;
        novi->next = NULL;
        l.back = novi;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Lista *lista = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    lista->back = lista->front = NULL;

    int jmb2[13] = { 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    [...]
    Pacijent p2 = noviPacijent("Mladen", "Markovic", "Milan", jmb2, 1.85, 75, 21);

    insertBack(p2, *lista);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at:

```
void insertBack(Pacijent p, Lista l)
```

This function takes a Lista value as argument, not a Lista pointer. This means that if you change anything about `l`, it will not have an effect outside of the function. When you call `insertBack`, you are actually copying your list, and then you add an element to the temporary list.

Edit:
The same is happening with your `assign` function, the changes you make to `p1` won't have any effect outside of the function because you pass it as a value and not as a pointer.